# MS Access: Merging a table row / query row to an existing table

Tags: ms-access, merge, datatable, ms-access-2007

does anyone know how I can add one dataset (=table row/query row) to an already existing table (that already contains a few entries).

I work on a database for a person with only a few database skills, so my idea was that all her entries (existing of many forms)  will be pasted in one table. Then she sees all her entries belonging to one dataset in a query. After this step this one dataset shall be pasted in a “master table” where all the data (ever inserted into the database) is inside and that is later used for some analysis.

We really need that pasting process (from table row/query row to master table) to prevent unwanted mistakes. The other solutions I found in the internet were not a very helpful problem solution.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Your question is rather vague but how 'bout using an INSERT statement.

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql` tag unless you're asking about MySQL. MS Access != MySQL.

Comment: So you want to copy data to a non-normalized table? How will this really help user? Users should not work directly with tables and queries, just forms and reports. Build those objects to meet user requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast reactions. I am working on a material-handling database. My idea is that the user works with forms to fill in the table for the one single material she is handling right now. At the end she sees all the data she has entered for this one material (with a report). This I already have implemented. But now I want to make it possible that she can paste the data (for this one single material) after having seen the data in the report into the existing master table where the data of all materials is stored.

Comment: I would love to use a button for this. But before I can try to figure out which VBA Code I need to use I need to know how the table (that she fills out) can be added to the existing master table.

Comment: @Rene. Thank you for your idea. It could work out. Because I would like to keep the database as simple as possible (that my colleagues in this developing country better understand how the database works) I would be happy to know if there is a way without an INSERT statement.

Comment: With the input from @Rene to use the INSERT statement I found this page which helped me very much. Thank you so much.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: Welcome to SO @CP-W. Please, post what you have found as an answer and mark it as correct so the question will be closed

Comment: Sorry I am new here :) I made an append query. It is like a normal query but the query will be attached to an existing table. In the criteria for the query i entered in that ID=1. So now the first row of table related to all the forms will be attached to the master table. The advantage is that if the user accidently opens a new record he does not destroy the master table, because only one row is added. Before the attach query adds the row to the master table I used a report (based on a query with criteria ID=1) to

Comment: give the user the opportunity to check exactly what is pasted to the master table. Thank you all!